# How can I DENY a SQL Server Database User from seeing tables in a specific schema? VIEW DEFINITION doesn't seem to work

Tags: sql-server, permissions, schema, azure-sql-database, ssdt

This is somewhat of an X/Y Problem: my *original problem* is that I want to use SSDT to maintain my database design, with the catch that my database design uses two schemas:

- The `dbo` schema that contains tables and views that are defined in my SSDT project.

  - All of these tables, views and procedures are defined in the `.sqlproj`.
- Another schema, `dynamic`, which contains tables and views that are managed by the application code itself and should *not* be managed by SSDT.

  - None of these objects, like `CREATE TABLE dynamic.DataForMay2021`, exists in the `.sqlproj`.

The problem is that SSDT's *Schema Compare* feature will always compare the entire SQL Server database to the `.sqlproj` SSDT project - which means it will look for the `dynamic.DataForMay2021` table in the `.sqlproj` (which doesn't exist) so it generates a `DROP TABLE dynamic.DataForMay2021` (which I don't want), which means I have to manually Exclude all objects in the Schema Comparison window before generating the migration script.

I reasoned that a way around this shortcoming is to run the SSDT Schema Comparison under a different `LOGIN`/`USER` that only has access to the `dbo` schema and not the `dynamic` schema.

I was able to create a new `LOGIN` and `USER`, however I haven't been able to successfully *hide* the `dynamic` schema from that user or login, despite trying these steps:

```
-- Connected to `master` using my Azure DBA:
CREATE LOGIN [SsdtSchemaCompareLogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'*****';

-- Disconnect and reconnect to my database:
CREATE USER [SsdtSchemaCompareUser] FOR LOGIN [SsdtSchemaCompareLogin] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]

-- Prevent `SsdtSchemaCompareUser` from seeing any of the `dynamic` schema objects:

DENY SELECT          ON SCHEMA::[dynamic] TO SsdtSchemaCompareUser;
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[dynamic] TO SsdtSchemaCompareUser;
```

However if I create a new SSMS session as `SsdtSchemaCompareLogin` I am still able to see all of the objects in the `dynamic` schema through the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME;
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

...and if I use SSMS's Object Explorer while connected as `SsdtSchemaCompareLogin` then I'm also able to see of the tables in the `dynamic` schema.

SSDT's Schema Comparison feature itself complains with these errors:

> [Warning] The target login is not a member of the 'loginmanager' role. The comparison will be restricted to database scoped elements.
> [Error] The reverse engineering operation cannot continue because you do not have View Definition permission on the 'MyDatabase' database.

---

So how can I prevent `SsdtSchemaCompareUser` from enumerating the contents of the `dynamic` schema?

Comment: For your original issue have you looked at https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer?

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you for the suggestion, however that project doesn't seem to relate to SSDT's Schema Compare feature.

Comment: Ah I thought you could use it for that too but maybe not... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/use-deployment-contributors-to-customize-database-build-and-deployment?view=sql-server-ver15#common-tasks

Comment: But back to your original plan you can't see object definitions by default in SQL Server so the permissions must be being granted in someway. Does public role have any permissions granted to it?

Comment: @MartinSmith I found out that `SsdtSchemaCompareUser` was a member of `db_owner` - after removing the user from the `ROLE` then the objects in the `dynamic` schema are no-longer visible (hurrah!) - but now SSDT complains that `SsdtSchemaCompareUser` has _any_ `DENY` permissions at all (wat?!) - is it possible to hide the fact the user is denied permissions on specific objects from that user? i.e. is it possible to both `DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[dynamic]` *and* to deny knowing that the `dynamic` schema exists at all, so it won't complain?